# How exactly does the parameter in "super" of javascript classes work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently going through the official reactJS Tutorial: 
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html
Though I'm not a total newbie to javascript, I'm still inexperienced in many aspects, and that's especially true for the OOP part of javascript.

I just recently how super basically works. Looking at the official API here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super 
and here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

I learned that super calls the constructor of the parent class. 
So when I'm extending a class, I can use super() to define what's being inputted into the constructor of the parent class.

Now, looking at this example from https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain:

```js
"use strict";

class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(sideLength) {
    super(sideLength, sideLength);
  }
  get area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
  set sideLength(newLength) {
    this.height = newLength;
    this.width = newLength;
  }
}

var square = new Square(2);
```

The square class has a constructor which puts its input into the two parameters of the parent class's constructor. This seems perfectly fine to me, since all the parameters of the parent class's constructor are taken into consideration by the super().

However, when I'm looking at this example from the reactJS tutorial, I'm a bit confused:

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}
      >
        {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, the Component class's constructor is called, and the parameter "props" is inserted into it. However, since I have no knowledge about the constructor of the "vanilla" component class, I wonder how this can actually work? Oo Okay, maybe the component class's constructor has no "default" parameters to it, then it's fine. But if this isn't the case, how does the constructor know how to handle this new parameter? Whether it "overwrites" the first or the second already existing parameter, or whether it shall just add the new parameter to the existing list of parameters.

And lets assume that the component class's constructor is "empty" by default. When I started extending this class and have already added, say three parameters to it's constructor, how does it know how to handle a fourth or fifth parameter and so on?
Looking at the behavior of common javascript functions, I'd expect chaos to ensue ^^

Answer (score 1):

In the example provided by ReactJS tutorial, Square extends Component.

When creating a new React component it is not mandatory to override the constructor, but if you do so you MUST call `super(props)` because otherwise the base Component class would not be properly initialized (in this case the component would not receive the props passed to it before it's first render which would be bad).

You do not instanciante React component yourself by calling `new MyComponent(props)`, but React will do it when calling React.createElement or when using jsx `<MyComponent {...props} />`.

More generally, if you extend a class, you must have knowledge of the class you're extending, that includes the parameters required by the constructor.

If you're overriding the constructor of a class, you must honor the contract of the class's documentation. That includes calling the base constructor. If the base constructor does something, you must maintain what it does by explicitely calling it.

Often, the same goes for the overriden methods: if you want to preserve the initial function of a method, you should call it in the overriden version

```
anOverridenMethod(...arguments) {
    doSomethingBefore();
    super.anOverridenMethod(...arguments);
    doSomethingAfter();
}
```

But actually in React most of the overridable methods (componentWillReceiveProps, shouldComponentUpdate...) do not have implementation at all so you don't need to bother calling the base method. The most common usecase of super is therefore in the constructor.

That said, in React, composition is preferred over inheritance (React component are not really meant to be extended)

[See this ressource discuting the difference between the two concepts](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)